# Dependencybot or similar free tool on bitbucket

Tags: python, django, bitbucket

Anyone, who knows any online free tool like [dependabot](https://dependabot.com/) of Github for bibucket, whereby a bot can raise a Pull Request on bitbucket just incase if the dependency has an update? I want to use it on the Django project

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [renovate](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate) and decide if it is what you're looking for.

It provides similar features, the main difference compared to dependabot would be that you need to take care of running and setting it up by yourself (i.e., self-hosting is required). The README.md in the product repository provides all the details.

Comment: you could improve this answer by elaborating on what features this tool provides.